# Determine $\bigcap_{x \in A} \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$ where $A=\{ x \in \Bbb R\mid x > \pi\}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Determine $\bigcap_{x \in A} \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$ where $A=\{ x \in \Bbb R\mid x > \pi\}.$

Isn’t $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2}) = (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$?

I’m familiar with that $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}A_n= \{a \mid \exists n \in \Bbb N : a \in A_n \}$.

Now I would need to find $\bigcap_{x \in A}  (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$ but this feels odd since I’m not iterating over $n$ anymore and would get something like $(\frac1n, \pi - \frac{1}{n^2})$?

This was a practice question for learning about $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

Answer (score 2):

$\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$ cannot depend on $n$ so it cannot be equal to $ (\frac1n, x-\frac{1}{n^2})$

Verify that $\bigcup_n (\frac 1 n, x-\frac 1 {n^{2}})=(0,x)$ and $\bigcap_{x \in A} (0,x)=(0,\pi]$.

Comment: I’m trying to build the bridge to $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. My fellow classmate instructed to think about the supremum with unions and infimum with intersections. This seems to be reversed here since $\sup 1/n = 1$ and $\inf 1/n = 0$?

Comment: The intervals are increasing. Their union is the interval from $\inf \frac 1 n$ to $\sup x-\frac  1{n^{2}}$. @Georgi